# If Loader's sourceComponent Item references its parent, and I set "loader.active = false", I get an error

Tags: qt, qml, runtime-error, qtquick2

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Item {
        id: loaderParent
        Loader {
            id: loader
            active: true
            sourceComponent: Item {
                parent: loaderParent
                x: parent.x
            }
        }
    }

    Item {
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            loader.active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I press any key, I get this error:

> qrc:/main.qml:16: TypeError: Cannot read property of null

Thought I suspect this error is harmless, I'd like an explanation or any idea for a fix/workaround?

Reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61853).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround: instead of fetching `parent.x`, fetch `loaderParent.x`. Still want to know why the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `Loader` appears to set the item parent to null on destruction. QML objects are not deleted immediately, instead they use `deleteLater()` which leaves the object alive for another event loop cycle.

This leads to a reevaluation of the binding expression, which is no longer possible since the parent is now null. I've had a more severe encounter with this behavior [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473495/setting-loader-active-to-false-doesnt-release-item-immediately).

A simple way to avoid it would be to not use the parent property which you already found, or to use a more complex binding expression such as `x: loader.active ? parent.x : someFailsafeValue`.

By using `onParentChanged: console.log(parent)` you can verify that the parent indeed changes to null when the loader is deactivated.

Comment: I left a comment on the other answer as well, but just for those who might only see this one, here are some relevant bug reports: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60344, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51995.